# Ruby Loops with Grandma

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

Okay, I'm trying to write a ruby simulation of my grandmother. I can't quite get the loop to work the way I'd like though. I want granny to respond with

> "OH, THAT REMINDS ME OF BACK IN (random year) ..."

when you answer her in all caps but I also want her to respond with

> "WHAT'D YOU SAY????"

when you don't use all caps. I can get each one to work separately but I can't seem to make a continuous loop of granny with her crazy responses. Here's the code:

```
puts 'HELLO SONNY! WHAT\'S NEW IN THE WHO\'S IT WHAT\'S IT?'
response = gets.chomp

while response == response.upcase
  puts 'OH, THAT REMINDS ME OF BACK IN ' + (rand(50) + 1905).to_s + '...'
  response = gets.chomp
end

while response != response.upcase
  puts 'WHAT\'D YOU SAY????'
  response = gets.chomp
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you obviously just started learning Ruby (I started with the same tutorial), I just wanted to point out that you don't have to escape characters in a string if you use double quotes "" instead of single quotes. It is convenient in simple situations like these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that once you exit the first while loop, you're never returning back to it.  Try something like this:

```
while true
  response = gets.strip
  if response == response.upcase
     puts msg1
  else
     puts msg2
  end
end
```

That'll run forever, until you decide to kill virtual-granny with Ctrl-C.

Comment: Great, that fixed her! Any upside to using .strip over .chomp?

Comment: I like it because it does both leading and trailing whitespace of any kind, where chomp just pulls off trailing newlines.  In this case, though, you don't really need either.

Comment: You can replace `while true` with `while response = gets.strip`.

Answer (score 0):

This program works, though Im a noob so it may not be the best way. Also my math is more creative then practical, the other guys is way better. :)

```
puts 'Talk to your grandma!'

while true
  say = gets.chomp

  if say == say.downcase
   puts 'WHAT DID YOU SAY? SPEAK UP!'

  else say == say.upcase
   puts "NO HONEY, NOT SINCE 19" + (rand(90) + 10).to_s 

  end

  break if say == 'bye'.upcase

end
```